# Run functional tests with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, continuous-integration, rest-assured, functional-testing

I am trying to create a project in Spring Boot, built with Gradle. I created functional tests with Rest Assured. My service is running at localhost and when I run ./gradlew build, my unit tests pass, but my functional tests fail. When I run them through the IDE with a running service in the background they all pass. Can I configure my gradle build to launch the service before trying to execute the tests.

I don't know what to try. I want to run them in a CI script.

Comment: How about a `tasks.test.dependsOn` to start the service, and a `tasks.test.finalizedBy` to stop it?